# Android: Custom Adapter with ViewHolder, OnCheckedChangedListener and TextChangedListener

Tags: java, android, android-listview, custom-adapter

I'm new to Android and Java programming and I've come across a problem recently. I've been searching an answer for hours, but I wasn't successful.
I have a custom ListView and a custom adapter, with a row containing a CheckBox and an EditText. Whenever it is displayed for the first time, it is OK, but when I scroll down, it starts to change the values of the CheckBox and the EditText.

Here is my row_edit.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/bonus"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:inputType="numberSigned"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox_person"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/bonus"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Item_edit (item of adapter):

```
public class Item_edit {
    private String meno;
    private boolean ucast;
    private int bonus;

    public Item_edit(String meno, boolean ucast, int bonus) {
        super();
        this.meno = meno;
        this.ucast = ucast;
        this.bonus = bonus;
    }

    public String getMeno() {
        return meno;
    }

    public boolean getUcast() {
        return ucast;
    }

    public int getBonus() {
        return bonus;
    }

    public void setMeno(String meno) {
        this.meno = meno;
    }

    public void setUcast(boolean ucast) {
        this.ucast = ucast;
    }

    public void setBonus(int bonus) {
        this.bonus = bonus;
    }
}
```

The ListView wasn't smooth, when I was scrolling and that is why I decided to use a ViewHolder.
Adapter_edit:

```
public class Adapter_edit extends ArrayAdapter<Item_edit> {
    private final Context context;
    private final ArrayList<Item_edit> itemsArrayList;
    private final Edit edit;

    public Adapter_edit(Context context, ArrayList<Item_edit> itemsArrayList, Edit edit) {

        super(context, R.layout.row_edit, itemsArrayList);
        this.edit = edit;
        this.context = context;
        this.itemsArrayList = itemsArrayList;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder = null;

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_edit, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            //Log.e("NewHolder", "position = " + position);
            holder.checkBox = (CheckBox) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.checkBox_person);
            holder.bonus = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.bonus);
            convertView.setTag(holder);

            holder.checkBox.setText(itemsArrayList.get(position).getMeno());
            holder.checkBox.setChecked(itemsArrayList.get(position).getUcast());
            holder.bonus.setText(Integer.toString(itemsArrayList.get(position)
                    .getBonus()));

            holder.checkBox
                    .setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

                            itemsArrayList.get(position).setUcast(isChecked);
                        }
                    });

            holder.bonus.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                    try {

                        if (itemsArrayList.get(position).getBonus() != Integer
                                .parseInt(s.toString()) && !edit
                                .getUcast(position)) {
                            itemsArrayList.get(position).setBonus(
                                    Integer.parseInt(s.toString()));
                            itemsArrayList.get(position).setUcast(true);
                        }
                    }
                    catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                        itemsArrayList.get(position).setBonus(0);
                    }

                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                }

                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
                }
            });

        }

        else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.checkBox.setText(itemsArrayList.get(position).getMeno());
        holder.checkBox.setChecked(itemsArrayList.get(position).getUcast());
        holder.bonus.setText(Integer.toString(itemsArrayList.get(position)
                .getBonus()));

        return convertView;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        CheckBox checkBox;
        EditText bonus;
    }
}
```

After debugging with LogCat I know that there are only 8 holders generated (because there are (0-7) items that fit my screen). These are being reused, when I scroll down. There are no OnCheckedChangeListeners and TextChangedListeners created for items with position greater than 7.

I have no idea what to do. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally got the answer.

I extended the EditText making my own class UpgEditText, that was capable of method setOnTextChangedListener which means to remove existing TextWatcher and add a new one.

UpgEditText

```
public class UpgEditText extends EditText {
    public UpgEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    public UpgEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public UpgEditText(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    TextWatcher watcher = null;

    public void setOnTextChangedListener(final int position, final Adapter_edit adapter) {
        if (watcher != null) {
            this.removeTextChangedListener(watcher);
        }

        watcher = new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                try {
                    adapter.itemsArrayList.get(position).setBonus(
                            Integer.parseInt(s.toString()));
                }
                catch (Exception e) {
                }
            }
        };
        this.addTextChangedListener(watcher);
    }
}
```

I also used a ViewHolder normally:

```
public class ViewHolder {
    CheckBox chBoxUcast;
    UpgEditText edTBonus;
}
```

CustomAdapter getView() method:

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder = null;

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_edit, parent, false);

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.chBoxUcast = (CheckBox) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.checkBox_person);
            holder.edTBonus = (UpgEditText) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.bonus);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }
        else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.edTBonus.setOnTextChangedListener(position, this);
        holder.chBoxUcast
                .setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        itemsArrayList.get(position).setUcast(isChecked);
                    }
                });

        holder.chBoxUcast.setText(itemsArrayList.get(position).getMeno());
        holder.chBoxUcast.setChecked(itemsArrayList.get(position).getUcast());
        holder.edTBonus.setText(Integer.toString(itemsArrayList.get(position)
                .getBonus()));

        return convertView;

    }
```

Everything works fine now. Everytime a convertView is recycled, I only change the listeners and it works well.